# Graph not showing results from 'for' loop in Python

Tags: python, graph

I am trying to generate a graph from my code. I know from the 'print' command that the equation is at least partially working, but the graph it is generating is blank. I am not sure why, or if there is another way?

I have tried code without a 'for' loop, but it keeps generating error messages, which is why I have tried this method. This includes np.linspace, which comes up with "'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer".

The code needs to find the voltage of a given system by checking the Voltage at particular times between 0 and 10 seconds, with 0.1 second steps. Thank you in advance.

```
 for t in np.arange(0, 10, 0.1):
     V = (math.e**(-0.06*np.pi*t))*math.sin(2*t - np.pi)
     print(V, 'Volts')
    
 fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
 ax.plot(t, V)
 ax.set_title('Voltage over Time')
 ax.set_xlabel('Time(s)')
 ax.set_ylabel('Voltage (V)')
```

Answer (score 0):

V and t need to be vectors if you want represent the graph over time
So first you create two vectors with `np.arange` an then iterate in the for loop to compute each `V[i]` according to the `x[i]` through the `enuerate`
Here's a solution

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
V = np.zeros(x.shape)
for i,t in enumerate(x):
    V[i] = (math.e ** (-0.06 * np.pi * t)) * math.sin(2 * t - np.pi)
    print(V, 'Volts')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
ax.plot(x, V)
ax.set_title('Voltage over Time')
ax.set_xlabel('Time(s)')
ax.set_ylabel('Voltage (V)')
plt.show()
```

Eventually, you don't need any loop and use vectorized computation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np
t = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
V = (math.e ** (-0.06 * np.pi * t)) * np.sin(2 * t - np.pi)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
ax.plot(t, V)
ax.set_title('Voltage over Time')
ax.set_xlabel('Time(s)')
ax.set_ylabel('Voltage (V)')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code you are writing the same value in V all the time, so you only plot a value. You have to save V in a list and plot the list and the `np.arange`.

```
 V = []
 for t in np.arange(0, 10, 0.1):
     volt=(math.e**(-0.06*np.pi*t))*math.sin(2*t - np.pi)
     V.append(volt)
     print(volt, 'Volts')
    
 fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
 ax.plot(np.arange(0,10,0.1), V)
 ax.set_title('Voltage over Time')
 ax.set_xlabel('Time(s)')
 ax.set_ylabel('Voltage (V)')
```

The final plot looks like this:
[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqDDL.png)